# Order statistics on substrings of a string

Tags: python, algorithm, memory

I have a long string `s` of size `n` and an integer `i`. I am interested in the `i`th substring of `s` under the lexicographical order.

The naive approach is to create the set of all substrings of `s`, and then get the `i`th order statistic of that set. This approach takes `O(n^2)` time but constructing the set of all substrings of `s` is way too memory intensive.

Is there a more "memory-friendly" approach?

Comment: If by "substring" you mean any subset of consecutive characters from your input string `s`, then there are indeed O(n^2) such strings.  How many indexes `i` do you need to study?  I guess that you need a fixed number of `i`s (1, for instance), because if you need all the possible indexes, then the computation time requires sorting all the substrings, which takes O(n^2 log n) instead of O(n^2).  Is this a correct guess?

Comment: @EOL the standard quickselect algorithm for finding an element in a list of size n is O(n), not O(n log(n)).

Comment: @btilly: Indeed. O(n^2 log n) is the time complexity for sorting (naively) all the substrings–as opposed to O(n^2) for only finding the i-th string for a single i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A substring is a prefix of a suffix of a string. You can get a sorted list of suffixes in time O(n) using one of the algorithms referred to in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array. The one referred to in Juha Kärkkäinen and Peter Sanders (2003). "Simple linear work suffix array construction is reasonably simple.

From a sorted list of suffixes some sort of lazy merge scheme should get you a sorted list of prefixes of suffixes = sorted list of substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of getting the starting character of the ith string:

```
s = "robert"

cumulative = 0
for c,num in sorted((j,i+1) for i,j in enumerate(reversed(s))):
    print c,num,cumulative
    cumulative+=x

b 4 0
e 3 4
o 5 7
r 2 12
r 6 14
t 1 20
```

Now from the results above (which can be generated quickly), you can see from the cumulative value that if i is between 0 and 4, we should use 'b' as the first character.
If i was between 7 and 12, we would use 'o' as the first character and so on.

To verify this we can look at the ordered sub strings (see that between 7 and 12 they all start with 'o') (starting with index 0, inclusive of the 7, exclusive of the 12):

```
print sorted([s[a:b] for a in range(n+1) for b in range(a+1,n+2)])
['b', 'be', 'ber', 'bert', 'e', 'er', 'ert', 'o', 'ob', 'obe', 'ober', 'obert', 'r', 'r', 'ro', 'rob', 'robe', 'rober', 'robert', 'rt', 't']
```

Now You can use this technique to get the first character. Once you have the **first** character, You know from the cumulative value how many substrings you have gone past. We can subtract this cumulative value from i. Now we look at a new string which is from the **first** (previously selected) character onwards (excluding the first character). We apply the same technique again (with the new string and the new i value) to get the second character.

Hopefully this makes sense. Good luck.

Comment: @Randomblue does this make sense to you?

Comment: There is an added complication if there are duplicate characters. You have to check how much the substrings from each of the duplicate characters overlap.